# Integration of two dimensional function over circle?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, expected-value

I have a two dimensional random variable $(X, Y)$, with pdf:
$$
f(x, y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\mathrm e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y^2)}~~\mathbf 1_{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2}
$$

The exercise is to find a $\mathbb{E}[R]$ where $R = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$.

Now, I know I can just compute $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \cdot f(x, y)\,dy\,dx$.

But I wanted to try solving this by computing the pdf of $R$. So I substituted $y = \pm \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$ into the integral to sum probability on the circle (I don't know if that phrasing is correct)

$$
f_{R}(r) = \underbrace{\int_{-r}^{r} f(x, \sqrt{r^2 - x^2})\,dx}_\text{"upper" circle} + \underbrace{\int_{-r}^{r} f(x, -\sqrt{r^2 - x^2})\,dx}_\text{"lower" circle} = \frac{2}{\pi} r e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2}
$$

My thinking was that those circles should cover whole 2D space and because $f(x, y)$ is a pdf then $f_{R}(r)$ should also be a valid pdf and the integral below should be equal to 1.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} f_{R}(r)\,dr = \frac{2}{\pi} \neq 1$$

But it's not. There must be some (possibly trivial) mistake but I don't know where the problem is (although it seems to be related to the fact that the integral is "over" circle, because there is a $\pi$). Any pointers?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution#Relation_to_random_vector_length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just just substitute for $y$.  You need to substitute for $\mathrm d y$ as well.

Now $y=\surd(r^2-x^2)\implies \mathrm d y = \left\lvert \dfrac r{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}\right\rvert\mathrm d r$

$$\begin{align}\int_\Bbb R\int_\Bbb R (x^2+y^2)^{1/2}\cdot\tfrac 1{2\pi}\mathrm e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y&=2\int_0^\infty\int_{-r}^r \lvert r\rvert\cdot\tfrac1 {2\pi}\mathrm e^{-r^2/2}\cdot\left\lvert\dfrac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}\right\rvert\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d r \\&=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\infty\int_0^r\dfrac{r^2\mathrm e^{-r^2/2}}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d r\end{align}$$

Which is pretty horrible to work with (well, it involves trig.), and why we often transform all the way to polar coordinates using the handy:

$$\iint_{\Bbb R^2} \phi(x,y)\mathrm d (x,y)=\int_0^\infty\int_0^{2\pi}\phi(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)\cdot r\,\mathrm d\theta\,\mathrm d r$$

Thus we immediately obtain

$$\begin{align}\int_\Bbb R\int_\Bbb R (x^2+y^2)^{1/2}\cdot\tfrac 1{2\pi}\mathrm e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d r&=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty\int_0^{2\pi} r^2\mathrm e^{-r^2/2}\mathrm d \theta\,\mathrm d r\\&=\int_0^\infty r^2\mathrm e^{-r^2/2}\,\mathrm d r\end{align}$$

Which is much easier to evaluate.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense :) I see that you are going for the whole expectation from the start and later on I can sort of figure out the pdf of $R$ by: 

$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{r} \frac{r^2 e^{-r^2/2}}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}} dx\,dr = \int_{0}^{\infty} r \int_{0}^{r} \frac{2}{\pi}\frac{r e^{-r^2/2}}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}} dx\,dr = \int_{0}^{\infty} r \left[r e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2}\right] dr = \int_{0}^{\infty} r f_{R}(r) dr$$


However is there a way to somehow go for $f_{R}(r)$ first?

Comment: Like maybe something along this way:
$$f_{R}(r) = \int \int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r} f(x, y) dy\,dx \stackrel{(*)}{=} \int \int_{-r}^{r} f(x, \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}) \left| \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2 - x^2}} \right| dr \, dx = ...$$
But at the point of $(*)$ I honestly don't know how to properly express the equations, as it seems that removing one integral with corresponding $dr$ gives the correct answer. Is there a way to properly express this or is this approach inherently invalid in my case?

Comment: It is : $$\begin{align}f_{\small R}(r)&=\mathbf 1_{r\in[0..\infty)}\int_{-r}^r\dfrac{r\, f_{\small X,Y}(x,\surd(r^2-x^2))}{\surd(r^2-x^2)}\,\mathrm d x+\mathbf 1_{r\in[0..\infty)}\int_{-r}^r\dfrac{r\, f_{\small X,Y}(x,-\surd(r^2-x^2))}{\surd(r^2-x^2)}\,\mathrm d x\\&=\dfrac{r\mathrm e^{-r^2/2}}{\pi}\mathbf 1_{r\in[0..\infty)}\int_{-r}^r\dfrac{1}{\surd(r^2-x^2)} \,\mathrm d x\\&=\left.\dfrac{r\mathrm e^{-r^2/2}}{\pi}\arctan\left(\dfrac{x}{\surd(r^2-x^2)}\right)\right\vert_{x=-r}^{x=r}~\mathbf 1_{r\in[0..\infty)}\\&= r\,\mathrm e^{-r^2/2}\,\mathbf 1_{r\in[0..\infty)}\end{align}$$